# How many more hard drives can I have on my laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, sata, hp-pavilion

My HP Pavilion 15-p157na came with two 5400 rpm hard drives and one optical drive. However, I see that the total number of SATA ports is four.

Does this mean that I still have one free slot to install a SATA SSD in this laptop? At least, can I replace the optical drive with an SSD caddy? I really need an SSD, but would like to know if this means swapping out one of the hard drives.

Thanks in advance for your valuable advice.

Comment: [No answer here?](https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c04507384)

Comment: @JanDoggen , nothing there. I also looked at the service manual. They only talk about replacing an existing spinning drive (9.5 mm). Mentions hybrid drives too. For performance reasons, I'd like a full SSD. I understand that all SATA standards are compatible https://superuser.com/questions/1007497/are-laptop-hard-drives-and-ssds-interchangeable. The question is with the physical dimensions, i.e. I would like to know if there is an extra hard drive bay (seems unlikely in a 15-inch laptop with 2 spinning + optical drive). I am unsure if the 4th port is just an eSATA port and hence not suitable.